# C++ Builder not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: c++builder

I have a project (newly started) where C++ Builder is not stopping at any of the breakpoints.  I have ensured that I am in Debug mode (not release), Linker->Full Debug Information = True, C++ Compiler->Debug Configuration, C++ Compiler->Debugging->Debug Information = true, Debug Line Number Information = true, Expand Inline Functions = true.

I haven't messed with any compiler / linker settings for this project. And I've tried it with two different versions of the compiler but in both cases, the breakpoints don't break.  I did try adding:
{ _asm { int 3 } } and when the program started, it hit it a few times so I know the code is being executed. (Besides, I placed a bunch of breakpoints all over the place and they don't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: @UncaAlby: That is not the case with C++Builder, where the debugger is integrated into the IDE.

Comment: Do you see a blue mark in the gutter (left side) of the code editor on the lines where you're setting the breakpoint? If not, it indicates code that will not be executed.

Comment: @KenWhite in that case, disregard my comment.

Comment: @KenWhite, there aren't any blue marks in the gutter.  Only the line numbers and the line number hash marks.  The breakpoint dots are red.

Comment: There should be blue dots in the gutter for lines that do not have bookmarks set. If they're not there, then the compiler does not see them as lines where a breakpoint can be set. Have you tried doing a complete build of your project after making sure everything is configured for debugging? (Not just a compile, but a Project->Build?)

Comment: Yes.  I've done a Project->Clean, then a complete rebuild.

Comment: I should point out that at this point, I only have one form in the project and none of the lines of code have any blue dots.  I can make changes to the code and the behavior of the application changes. (So the code is getting executed.)  Strange ....

Comment: What version of C++Builder are you using? Also, did you look at the Project Manager to make sure that you're in the Debug build configuration?

Comment: @pollarda how did it go? did my approach help? also do you use your own components and packages (they can mess this up too and need rebuilding)?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error or something very similar. To detail what happens for me, I start my project in debug mode, the program seems to stop at the breakpoint but it's a crash of the app (independently of breakpoint position). During the execution of the program, I have no blue dots in any line of my code. I'm working with **C++ builder 10.4** and using **Windows 64 bits**.

The solution that I used is to compile again my whole project. I'm not able to reproduce the error so I can't say if it's a solution or just a lucky shot.

Another point, before this bug my project has already been started successfully in debug mode. The bug appears at times and seems random. I can get this error **without** changing any line or project option.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 reasons for this (beware the blue dots are visible only when your program is running!):

1. **Your code does not execute**

   if you put breakpoint on stuff never executed it will never stop. Also some lines tend to be optimized out so sometimes help to disable optimizations while debugging.
2. **Your project file is messed up**

   this happens time to time. What usually helps is:

   1. delete all temp files `*.tds,*.map,*.obj*.exe` in your project
   2. move the `#pragma hdrstop` line in infected file to different location

      usually you need to try more locations until it works ... mostly going down few lines even after all the includes.
   3. save all files and then compile & run

   If Blue dots appear on the left side of the code your project is repaired and you can move the `#pragma hdrstop`to its original location.

However sometimes nothing helps. In such case create a new project. That mimics your old (Form number and names) and then just copy the `*.bdsproj` file into your old one.

Its a good idea to backup your working project file as IDE tend to break it occasionally (its rare but it happens)

In case you got different compiler version use your file extentions (they changed them slightly)

Once all fails there is still possibility of debugging by using `F8` for stepping from place where blue bullets are present you usually can step into the unbreakpointable areas ...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention which version you are using, but I'll guess it is an older one and your project is 64 bit. I have experienced this bug myself. They fixed it since, but the 64 bit C++ Builder debugger is still pretty much useless for larger projects (i.e. breakpoints work again, but the debugger crashes past the first breakpoint). Upgrade to 10.4 Update 1, just don't expect too  much unless you work with small single thread projects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you chosen the debug config in the project manager as it is shown in the picture attached?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."